# Flexbox/CSS Wrap Order? Best way to wrap/hide a flexbox div to hide it?

Tags: html, css

I have 3 elements in a flex container

```
[col1-logo][col2-userdeets][col3-menu]
```

Via media queries, I can have col2 disappear/wrap on smaller screens when it doesn't fit, which is what I want. However - the width of col2 and col3 aren't fixed; their contents are db-generated. I could fix col2 if I had to but col3 generates it's menu from a DB..

What I want, on a large screen, is that if col3 is too wide for col2 to fit, that col2 is wrapped/hidden..

```
[col1-logo][col3-menu]
   [col2-userdeets]
```

where the 2nd row would be hidden via overflow:hidden; My thought was to break up col2/col3 into their own container maybe..but I don't want that to screw up the rest of the header/media queries..? Any other idea's?

https://jsfiddle.net/koeL8z6c/3/

In this fiddle, the div.user_info should disappear if there is too many elements in the menu (or if the screen is slightly smaller, but much smaller and the user_info div is hidden and the menu is hidden and replaced with an icon)

I also realized overflow: hidden to hide it may not work so hot because of my drop down menu, which disappears obviously when overflow is hidden..

I know I could do this relatively simply with Javascript, but I'd prefer to keep it CSS only - I could figure out the submenu overflow hidden problem if only I could get the `div.header_right`'s contents to wrap BEFORE `div.header_container`'s content wraps..? So parent always wraps first?

Answer (score 0):

I've achieved the effect I am looking for, finally..

Had to use some trickery with negative stuff and made it basically 'wrap' under the top of the browser window..

https://jsfiddle.net/koeL8z6c/10/

CSS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:400|Source+Sans+Pro:400|Amatic+SC:200,300,400|Open+Sans+Condensed:200,300,400|Abel:400,600,700|Share+Tech+Mono:400');

$fonts: Roboto, Helvetica, sans-serif;
$monofont: 'Share Tech Mono', fixed;
$primary: #aaabbb;
$background: #000;
$modalBg: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
$modalContentBg: rgb(64,64,64);

$logoFont: 'Amatic SC';

$footerbg: #333;

$break-narrow: 400px;
$break-mid: 720px;
$break-wide: 1080px;

* {box-sizing: border-box;}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font: 100% Roboto, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #aaabbb;
  background-color:#000;
  height: 100%;
}

body > div.container::before {
  background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532326461512-9a41c624fa09?fm=jpg&q=30&w=2560') center;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  filter: grayscale(15%) sepia(8%) blur(8px) hue-rotate(0deg);
  z-index: -99;
}

header {
  background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.55);
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 1px 3px black);
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  //overflow: hidden;
}

header div.header_container {
  max-width: 1080px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3)
}

header div.header_logo {
  flex: 0 0 220px;
  height:60px;
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
}

header div.header_logo > a h1 {
  font-family: 'Amatic SC';
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
}

header div.header_right {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

header div.header_right div.user_info {
  position: relative;
  top: -50px;
  height: 0px;
  padding-right: 2rem;
}

header div.header_right div.user_info p {
  margin: 0;padding:0;
}
header div.navigation {
  height:60px;
}
header div.navigation div.menu nav.main {
  height:60px;
}
header div.navigation div.menu nav.main ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    height:60px;
}

header div.navigation div.menu nav ul li:hover label {
  padding-bottom:0.5rem;
}
header div.navigation div.menu nav ul li:hover nav.subnav {
  display:block;
}

header div.navigation div.menu nav.main ul li:hover {
  padding-bottom:0.5rem;
}
header div.navigation div.menu nav.main ul li label:hover {
  background-color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
  //padding-bottom:0.5rem;
  height:40px;
}
header div.navigation div.menu nav.main ul li label {
  padding-left: 0.5rem;
  padding-right: 0.5rem;
  padding-top: 0.25rem;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  font-family: 'Abel';
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  color: rgba(32, 32, 32, 0.8);
  background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  white-space: pre;
}

header div.navigation div.menu nav.main ul li {
//  display: inline-block;
  //position:relative;
margin-left: 0.5rem;
  align-self: flex-end;
}
header div.navigation div.menu nav.subnav ul {
  margin-left:-0.5rem;
  margin-top:0.5rem;
}
header div.navigation div.menu nav.subnav ul {
  display:block;
  //height: 60px;
}
header div.navigation div.menu nav.main ul li nav.subnav ul li:hover {
  padding-bottom:0;
  background-color:rgba(128,128,128,0.5);
}
header div.navigation div.menu nav.main ul li nav.subnav ul li {
  display:block;
  padding-left: 0.5rem;
  padding-right: 0.5rem;
  padding-top: 0.25rem;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  font-family: 'Abel';
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  background-color:rgba(32, 32, 32, 0.8);
}

header div.navigation div.menu nav ul li nav.subnav {
  display: none;
  position:absolute;
}

/* small */
@media screen and (max-width: $break-narrow) {
  div.menu {
    display: none;
  }
  div.user_info {
    display: none;
  }
}

/* small to medium */
@media screen and (min-width: $break-narrow) and (max-width: $break-mid) {
  div.menu {
    display: none;
  }
  div.user_info {
    display: none;
  }
}

/* above medium */
@media screen and (min-width: $break-mid + 1) {
}

/* medium to large */
@media screen and (min-width: $break-mid + 1) and (max-width: $break-wide - 1) {
  div.menu_icon {
    display: none;
  }
}

/* small thru large */
@media screen and (min-width: $break-narrow) and (max-width: $break-wide - 1) {
}

/* above large */
@media screen and (min-width: $break-wide) {
  div.menu_icon {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <div class="header_container">
        <div class="header_logo">
          LogoLogo!!
        </div>
        <div class="header_right">
          <div class="user_info">
            <p>Welcome, Username!</p>
            <p>You have 0 items in your cart.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="navigation">
            <div class="menu_icon">
              <a href="#"><i class="material-icons">dehaze</i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="menu">
              <nav class="main">
                <ul>
                  <li><label>Home</label>
                  <nav class="subnav">
                    <ul>
                      <li>imalink that</li>
                      <li>Subnav I SAID</li>
                      <li>subnavpoop</li>
                    </ul>
                  </nav>
                  </li>

                  <li><label>About</label>
                    <nav class="subnav">
                      <ul>
                        <li>Subnav</li>
                      </ul>
                    </nav> 
                  </li>
                  <li>
                  <label>Navigation</label>
                  </li>
                  <li><label>Links</label></li>
                  <li><label>And such</label></li>
                  <li><label>And such</label></li>
                  <li><label>And such</label></li>                                    
                    <!-- un/comment these two to see/hide the middle or resize window -->
                  <!--<li><label>And such</label></li>
                  <li><label>And such</label></li>-->
                  </ul>
              </nav>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```